# Jquery cannot select div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="contentChildren" class="frame">

<div id="icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fc7be680-c0a8c88d-1be20c00-e3a2814e">
 <a class="contentItem Article" href="http://localhost:9080/ekms/contentexplorer  /explorer.jsp?cn=contentExplorer.panel&et=openMenu&contentId=com.tms.cms.article.Article_fda4d360-c0a8c88d-ae8af400-e4f04255">
</div>

</div>
```

I have the above  html. i trying to use jquery to select the div inside the . that is the div id of "icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fc7be680-c0a8c88d-1be20c00-e3a2814e"

but it seems like it cannot be selected. i try using

```
$("icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fc7be680-c0a8c88d-1be20c00-e3a2814e").html();
```

but it returns null. This is the function i used

```
function _clickMenu(){              
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  var id = parent.attr("id");
  id = id.substr(5);

  $.getJSON(this.href, function(data){

  });
  var icon = "#icon_"+id;

  var x = $("#icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fc7be680-c0a8c88d-1be20c00-e3a2814e");
  alert("x : " + x.html());

  return false;
}
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think since there are `.` in the selector its taking it as class selector.
just try something like

```
$('div[id="icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fc7be680-c0a8c88d-1be20c00-e3a2814e"]').html()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the trick:

```
// instead of $(x), just use x.
alert("x : " + x.html());
```

x is still a valid jQuery object, so there's no need for another $() wrapper.

EDIT:

Just realized you're also using '.' in the ID. Which might even be OK for valid HTML, but jQuery uses dots to select class names. So it will recognize

```
$('#icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fda4d360-c0a8c88d-ae8af400-e4f04255')
```

as a selector for: id "icon_com", with classes "tms", "cms", "article", "Article_fda4d360-c0a8c88d-ae8af400-e4f04255".

Sure enough, this snippet works:

```
<div id="icon_com" class="tms cms article Article_fda4d360-c0a8c88d-ae8af400-e4f04255">
    <a class="contentItem Article" href="http://localhost:9080/ekms/contentexplorer  /explorer.jsp?cn=contentExplorer.panel&et=openMenu&contentId=com.tms.cms.article.Article_fda4d360-c0a8c88d-ae8af400-e4f04255">lorem ipsum</a>
</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var x = $("#icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fda4d360-c0a8c88d-ae8af400-e4f04255");
    alert("x : " + x.html());
});
</script>
```

+1 to xdazz's points, too.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I have understood after your explanation. but i wanted to select the div using icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fda4d360-c0a8c88d-ae8af400-e4f04255 as the id. So i am going to use solution by dku.rajkumar

Answer (score 1):

1.Your html don't have a div with id `icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fc7be680-c0a8c88d-1be20c00-e3a2814e`.

2.`$("icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fc7be680-c0a8c88d-1be20c00-e3a2814e")` is wrong, miss the `#`.

3.

```
var x = $("#icon_com.tms.cms.article.Article_fc7be680-c0a8c88d-1be20c00-e3a2814e");
alert("x : " + $(x).html());
```

is also wrong, just `x.html()`

Comment: i am sorry. the id was suppose to be the same as the div. and i didnt exclude the #.